# MDX split string?

Tags: string, ssas, mdx

I'm new to SSAS and MDX-scripts in general. My question is simple; is it possible to split a string in MDX? The reason for this is because I'm using:

```
username()
```

This function returns *DOMAIN\USERNAME* (Domain & Username). But I only want to use the username-part (thus splitting it by the "\"-char somehow) since this is what is stored in the database and I want to do a compare.

The call to **username()** is used to build another string:

```
StrToMember("{[User].[Username].&[" +username()+"]}")
```

Is this possible at all? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching on the web I found a solution on: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15f0a544-8d82-4926-ae5c-ce1f3f894deb/function-mdx-return-user-loged-username?forum=sqlanalysisservices

The solution looks like this:

```
nonempty([Plant].[Plant Name].[Plant Name].members,
([measures].[Plant Admin Count],
    StrToMember("{[User].[Username].&[" + mid(username, instr(username, "\")+1) + "]}") 
))
```

And it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

As you already have found out, `Mid` and `Instr` work in MDX. Actually, MDX "borrows" many VBA functions, especially for string manipulation.

There is a list of VBA functions supported by MDX and DAX at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510163.aspx. This list states it is for SQL Server 2012, but I would assume it is 99% correct for SQL Server 2008 and 2008R2 as well.

Comment: I was looking for some sort of list with MDX string functions but I couldn't find anything useful. Great to have a link now!